# AngularJs directives - how to get attributes values from within directive

Tags: angularjs

Any idea how to access attributes values from inside the directive?

```
    angular.module('portal.directives', [])
        .directive('languageFlag', ['$routeParams', function(params) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(attrs["data-key"]); // returns undefined
                console.log(element.attr('data-key')); // returns {{data-key}}
                angular.element(element).css('border', '1px solid red');
            };
        }]);
```

Html code is:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="lng in flags">
        <a class="lngFlag {{flag.Key}}" data-key="{{flag.Key}}" data-id="{{lng.Id}}" ng-click="changeLangHash({'lng':lng.Id })" language-flag></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: just follow camel case in case of dash -

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `$observe`:

> *Observing interpolated attributes*: Use `$observe` to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. `src="{{bar}}"`). Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to `undefined`. -- [directives doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

```
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('key', function(value) {
        console.log('key=', value);
    });
}
```

As @FMM mentioned in a comment, `data` is stripped by Angular when it normalizes the attribute name, hence the use of `key` above, rather than `dataKey`.

Comment: Thanks. It works on all attributes except for the ones with snake notations. Such as data-something. But I accept your answer because it actually works with other attributes.
I appreciate your effort and time.

Comment: It's likely that angular is trimming the `data` prefix (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive): "Optionally the directive can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant." It's probably a bad idea to start your (logical) attribute names with "data".

Answer (score 10):

try `attrs["dataKey"]` - this is the way that html parses attributes with dash (`-`).
if you want the value from the scope instead of `{{something}}`, you can do two things:

`scope[attrs['dataKey']]` - will work but shouldn't do this

or use [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse) but then don't use ``{{}}`

```
app.directive('languageFlag', ['$routeParams','$parse', function(params,$parse) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var value =  $parse(attrs.dataKey)(scope);
    console.log(value);
    angular.element(element).css('border', '1px solid red');
  };
}]);
```

or you can use [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate) the same way like `$parse` but with `{{}}`

Comment: Thanks for answering.
console.log(attrs["dataKey"]); // = undefined
console.log(scope[attrs['dataKey']]); // = undefined
I even removed all the {{}} and tried .$parse but still 'undefined'. Isn't there a way to simply access the underlying model at bind time?

Comment: Passing parent scope to the $parse (ex: `$parse(attrs.uid)($scope.$parent)` ) solved my issue

Comment: @g00fy But what if the attribute is a two way  binded value? My code will only parse it on directive load, but never notice the changes made to the variable (from the parent scope).

Answer (score 4):

angular strips 'data-' off any attributes, so if your attribute is 'data-key', just use 'key', not 'dataKey'

Comment: I have a attribute with name "data-actiontype" with just actiontype I am not getting the data from that attribute. Is that name is predefined ?

Comment: @Kathir Hard to say without seeing your code. Hopefully you've figured it out since you asked 14 hours ago. If not, you should be able to look at the answers on this page and try a couple different things, figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my tag below  `<input type="button" value="Ok" id=""  ng-click="getAttributejs($event)" class="" data-actiontype="kathir" />`   Currently I am removing `data-` from tag. I am not figured out still.

Comment: @Kathir you might want to post a new question, i and everyone else really need to see your angular directive code. It'll likely get answered pretty quick. Or put together a codepen/JSfiddler and provide that link

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using object notation if you are inside the link function of the directive, which gets the attrs parameter:

attrs.yourAttributeName

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I discovered is that **$attr** will convert attribute names to **lower-casing**.

`<input myTest="test" />`

Value can be obtained with this... `attr["mytest"]`

i.e.

`...link: function (scope, element, attr) { console.log(attr["mytest"]); ...}`